# TypeError in Python :c

Tags: python, typeerror

I am very new to Python and I'm working on some code for a bank account per-say and I'm having trouble creating the proper code to show the overall balance of the account after the account goes through changes. This following is my code;

```
account = 1000.
balance = 0

def deposit ( x, y):
    return x + account

def withdrawal (x, y):
    return account - x

def getbalance (account,depost,withdrawal):
    return account + deposit - withdrawal

print("1. Make a Deposit")
print("2. Make a Withdrawal")
print("3. Obtain Balance")
print("4. Quit")
choice = input("Make a selection from the option menu ")   

if choice == '1':
    num1 = int(input("Enter amount of Deposit: "))
    print("Enter Amount of Deposit. ", deposit(num1,1000))

elif choice == '2':
    num2 = int(input("Enter amount of Withdrawal: "))
    print(num2, "Withdrawal Processed. ", withdrawal(num2,1000))

elif choice == '3':
    balance=getbalance(account,deposit,withdrawal)
    print(balance, "Balance: ", balance(1000,deposit,withdrawal))
```

And I keep getting the follow typeError:

```
line 23, in getbalance
    return account + deposit - withdrawal
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'function
```

I would love any advice anyone has on this subject. Thank you everyone for your time.

Comment: Why this question is having 'c' tag ?

Comment: you forgot `()` in `return account + deposit() - withdrawal` or you have typo in `def getbalance (account,depost,withdrawal):`

Comment: Awesome thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deposit is not a variable it is a function

you should just update balance in each of functions instead of returning it out

For instance you could do something like this

```
balance = 1000.

while true
    if choice == '1':
        deposit = float(input("Enter amount of Deposit: "));
        balance += deposit
        print("Deposit of {} processed, new balance {}".format(deposit,balance))
    if choice == '2':
    ...
```

You also don't need . in python and also consider naming your variables more meaningfull

Comment: I'm trying to add in a balance after everything is accounted for. My code so far is: 

elif choice == '3':
    balance = float(input("Enter Balance amount: "));
    print("Balance: {}".format(balance));

And I cannot figure out how to display the balance after the deposit and withdrawals are through. I change all my code to what you've posted and it helped a lot but I still cannot get the overall total. Any other advice on this would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

It's a typo.

Your parameter is `depost`, but you're using `deposit` in the return statement. `deposit` happens to be a name of a function as well, so that's what's being used.

Comment: Problem is bit bigger as he is still passing that same function in code :) balance(1000,deposit,withdrawal)